# Dockerize framework tests "Failed to exec"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, galen

I wanted to dockerize galenframework tests. Here is what I have currently:

DockerFile

```
FROM node:8.6
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/galen
WORKDIR /usr/src/galen
COPY package.json /usr/src/galen/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/galen
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  galenframework:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/galen
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker_galen",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker with Galen",
  "dependencies": {
    "galenframework-cli": "2.3.5"
  }
}
```

after running `docker-compose up -d` I get following error:

> info Install exited unexpectedly npm info lifecycle
>   galenframework-cli@2.3.5~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall
>   script npm WARN docker_galen@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN
>   docker_galen@1.0.0 No license field. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 1 npm ERR! galenframework-cli@2.3.5 postinstall: node
>   postinstall.js npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   galenframework-cli@2.3.5 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I tried to rerruning this on java 8 alpine image because I thought this error might be related to java dependency, so first line of DockerFile changed to `FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN set -ex && \
    apk upgrade --update && \ . That did not help...
    apk add --update nodejs`

Comment: Try changing `npm install` with `yarn install` and see if it helps. Also do remember that `.:/usr/src/galen` volume mapping will override all the node_modules you had installed inside the dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Java to run Galen, so this should work

```
FROM java:8

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.11.4
ENV GALEN_VERSION 2.3.5

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default \
    && npm install -g galenframework-cli@$GALEN_VERSION

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now I will try to minimize the image... Maybe use alpine :P

Comment: you may run into issues with node and alpine